# How to save different objects in C++ where the datatype parameter is encapsulated?

Tags: c++

I have two classes as follows, a class named Participant and a class named MainControl.

Some sort of a competition is supposed to take place, the competition is between different participants and is supposed be run through the class MainControl using different methods.

However, now I face a major difficulty that I am unable to solve thus far. This is less of a code problem and more me not being able to understand how execute something.

Basically, I am supposed to be able to print a full list of the competitors and their data, sorted by the state they represent. However, I can't think about a way to save the participants in some sort of a data type that will enable this.

That is because I have some limitations:

-The class Participant has a single constructor, as defined below.

-I can't use friend on functions in Participant.

-The functions defined in MainControl and in Participant are the only functions allowed (this includes external functions as well regarding those classes).

-Arrays are the only datatypes I am able to use, and any other ones will need to be completely defined by me.

If I try to use an array containing participants, I face an error because an array cannot be defined because the class Participants doesn't have the constructor required.

To my understanding there is a way to overcome those limitations defining some sorts of private structs, however I can't understand how to do so, because to me no matter what type of object I define, I won't be able to use it because the parameters are private and I have no get functions.

I am looking for ideas, the two classes are posted below. **If there is a way to solve this using arrays I would love to see it**.

Ignore code errors as this is not the point.

Can anyone help please?

```
    class Participant
    {
        // relevant private members can be defined here, if necessary.
        string state_name;
        string song_name;
        int time_length;
        string singer_name;
        bool is_registered;
    public:
        Participant(string state, string song, int time, string singer):
        state_name(state),song_name(song),singer_name(singer),time_length(time),is_registered(false){
        }
        ~Participant() = default;
        string state() const;
        string song() const;
        int timeLength() const;
        string singer() const;
        int isRegistered() const; 
        void update(const string song, const int time, const string singer);
        void updateRegistered(const bool status);
    };
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Participant& p);

class MainControl
{
    // relevant private members can be defined here, if necessary.
    int max_time_length;
    int max_participants;
    int max_votes;
    int current_participants;
    Phase current_phase;
public:
    MainControl(int time_length = DEFAULT_MAX_TIME, int participants = DEFAULT_MAX_PARTICIPANTS, int votes = DEFAULT_MAX_VOTES) : max_time_length(time_length), max_participants(participants), max_votes(votes), current_phase(Registration), current_participants(0){
    };
    ~MainControl();
    MainControl& operator+=(const Participant& p);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MainControl& mc);
};
```

Comment: Looks like the instructor is trying to force a linked list on you, but it looks like they've left open the possibility of using [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) and writing your own `vector`. I'm not sure which one will be harder for you to successfully implement.

Comment: We haven't stuied about vectors yet. I am still completely stuck.

Comment: You can of course do an array of pointers. auto arr = new Participant[a size];

Comment: Do you mean that I should add another parameter in the class MainControl which will be look like: Participant* array? If so, I still don't understand how will I be able to use it in external methods, like those in the class Participant where I add a user. The array itself will be encapsulated.

Comment: "Arrays are the only datatypes I am able to use, and any other ones will need to be completely defined by me." What counts as data types? Does `std::ostream` count?

Comment: The only use of ostream we have studied is for printing, not sure where you are going with this. If there is a way to solve this using an array with pointers it would be preferable. I am allowed to define friend functions in MainControl although I would prefer not to.